# hooking exception handler in x86_64

Tags: exception, hook, x86-64

I am trying to hook my own asm code into the exception handling prologue path. For that, I thought of the path where I will change the exception handler address in the IDT with my own code and from there, I will call the actual handler.

Arch I am working on is x86_64.

I got couple of links that does the job for i386.
Links : http://mammon.github.io/Text/linux_hooker.txt
        http://phrack.org/issues/59/4.html
But I want it for x86_64, as asm instruction-set for exception prologue and epilogue is totally diff in both the arch.

I am not able to find related doc for x86_64 online.

I want to find the doc OR if someone can explain me, what all files and code come into the picture when exception occurs in x86_64 and how.

Thanks in advance.
Sapan Parikh